# Client Side File Upload to S3

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a NodeJS/Express webapp running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and I want to allow my users to upload profile pictures to AWS S3.
I want the client to directly upload to S3 because I’m planning to implement bigger file uploads later. I’m fairly new to NodeJS and AWS, how can I achieve what I’m looking for?

Comment: You can use a [pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) to upload the file directly to the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the high-level steps:

1. Enable CORS on your S3 bucket
2. The function that creates the presigned URL needs to have s3:putObject permissions. So add a policy with that permission to your S3 bucket to your AWS Elastic Beanstalk role.
3. Implement an endpoint in your NodeJS application that returns the pre-signed URL. [Generating a pre-signed URL using JavaScript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_Scenario_PresignedUrl_section.html)
4. Implement a file picker and uploader page in your NodeJS application. After the user selects their file, when they click upload, request the pre-signed URL and post the file to that URL endpoint
5. You will also want to consider if you want to make these files publicly available or only share with the signed-in users

Follow [this AWS blog guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/uploading-to-amazon-s3-directly-from-a-web-or-mobile-application/) for a detailed walk-through using Amazon API gateway and Lambda. In your case, you could directly implement the presigned URL generation in the NodeJS code and expose the API endpoint via express instead of using Lambda and API Gateway.

Example policy to attach to Elastic Beanstalk:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "<my-bucket-arn-expression>/*",
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
```